# Prove that norms are equivalent

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

$ \| * \|_a ,\| * \|_b  $ - norms in vector space $ X $. Any linear functional  $f: X \to K$ is continuous towards $ \| * \|_a \iff$ is continuous towards $ \| * \|_b $. Prove that these norms are equivalent.

I need to prove that $ C_1  \| x \|_a \leq  \| x \|_b \leq C_2 \| x \|_a $. I know that $ | f(x) | \leq M_1\| x \|_a$ and  $ | f(x) |\leq M_2\| x \|_b$. But what should be next?

Comment: Hint: You can see that $\|x\|_{2} \leq \|x\|_{1}$ by squaring both the sides. Now you can also see after a little manipulation that $\|x\|_{1} \leq n\|x\|_{1}$, where $n$ represents the dimension of the vector space. The second inequality can be arrived at by observing that $|x_{i}| \leq \|x\|_{2}, for i = 1, 2,... n.$

Comment: @PrinceKumar I don't think the $1$ and $2$ here refer to the standard $1$-norm and $2$-norm; they're just indices.

Comment: @Tom 's right, I should have called it in different way

Comment: @Tom The relation $C_{1}\|x\|_{1} \leq \|x\|_{2} \leq C_{2}\|x\|_{1}$ represents the equivalence of norms. So, I very much think that they are referring to standard 1-norm and 2-norm.

Comment: @pupilx Ohk. Got it. Read it backwards. :D

Comment: @pupilx You can take that functional $f$ to be the norm $\|*\|_a$. It is a continuous functional with respect to itself. So, it must be continuous with respect to $\|*\|_b$. Do the same by taking $f$ to be the norm $\|*\|_b$.

Comment: @PrinceKumar A norm is __not__ a linear functional...